# Apps (like calculator) appear in the dock without adding them there

Tags: dock

Like the title suggests, I noticed calculator was in the dock without me adding it there. Could this be a virus or something? I have Macbook pro 13 inch from 2015. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried removing it to see if it reappears?

Comment: Also, if the app doesn't normally live in the Dock, and you launch it, then it's there.  If you happen to grab it and move it to another position on the dock, the OS interprets that as you wanting to keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in System Preferences->Dock & Menu Bar

If you have the "Show recent apps in Dock" enabled

[image: doc]

Comment: How is this different from [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/449970/359458)?

Answer (score 0):

Recently used apps are by default shown in the Dock.

You can disable that by choosing System Preferences->Dock & Menu Bar and then deselecting  the “Show recent applications in Dock” checkbox in macOS Monterey. In macOS Ventura,  go to System Settings, click Desktop & Dock  in the sidebar, and go to Dock on the right and scroll down a bit for the same setting.